# What's the meaning of "community involvement"?

Tags: modifiers, attributive-nouns, qualifiers

She saw **community involvement** as crucial.

How the word "community" is modifying the word"involvement"?how the meaning is changing after adding the word "community" to the word "involvement"?How a native speaker will interpret it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many noun adjuncts, the combination of nouns forms a compound with a lexical meaning of its own.  The meaning, in this case, could be glossed as "involvement of the community", where "the community" is understood from context.  For example in the context of a school, "the community" would be the people of the village or town that the school is in.

Comment: Can it be interpreted (as an alternative to what you said)"actively participate in various activities within a specific community "?

Comment: How is that different from what I said?

Comment: I mean, if a we are talking about an organisation, then the involvement of the community would mean participating in various activities with members of that community, within that community.

Comment: Ok, but after formation of compound noun we need to interpret its meaning according to our knowledge. (Because dictionary is not useful in many types of similar cases)

Comment: Yes, that is what I said.  The compound will have some meaning.

Comment: I think It can be easily misinterpreted as dictionary is not providing meaning of all compound nouns. (Like this)

Comment: As @Sam said in its first comment, depending on the context, "community involvement" may also be understood as * her participation in community life*.

Comment: @Graffito yes, involvement in community life vs involvement of community in something (both is possible )

Comment: "We asked her how she and her family have managed dual careers, three sons, significant mission responsibilities, and community involvement" here "involvement in community life" is suitable rather than "involvement of the community."

Comment: Sam, _participate_ is a verb, _involvement_ is a noun.

Comment: @KateBunting do u think " involvement of community" is correct??

Comment: James has already used _involvement of the community_ in his answer. I was suggesting that your version should be _active participation_.

Comment: @KateBunting I think "community involvement" may have different meaning determined by context.

Comment: "Involvement of the community in something" is the obvious meaning, but  in the context of the sentence you quoted above it does appear to mean "involvement of her in the community".